# How to mock method that has return type from of the (bool, string)?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, xunit

The following function has a return value of `(bool, string)`. How to Moq it to be ready for unit testing.

```
Task<(bool, string)> CreatePhoneCertificate(
    int orderId, 
    CancellationToken cancellationToken);
```

```
   var mockInsuranceService = new Mock<IInsuranceService>();
   mockInsuranceService
  .Setup(x => x.CreatePhoneCertificate(12345, It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
  .ReturnsAsync(???);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a value tuple with desired values:

```cs
mockInsuranceService.Setup(x => x.CreatePhoneCertificate(12345, It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
    .ReturnsAsync((true, "someString"));
```

Read more:

- [Tuple types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples#tuples-vs-systemtuple)

Comment: @MJavadSalehi please be sure to copy-paste the full code. Your original one was missing a parenthesis (which I added here and in the original question). I have this code perfectly compiling at my machine.